# How to do vlookup in python?

Tags: python

I have a dataset like below

category_data

```
    userid       Frequency  Category    SubCategory
0   axisbankltdi    13705   BFSI        Banking
1   nokiasiemens34  8642    Telecom     EnterpriseTelecom
2   videocond2h     4699    Utilities   DTH
3   pnb             3201    BFSI        Banking
4   nokiasiemens7   2536    Telecom     EnterpriseTelecom
5   one97paytm      2318    BFSI        Payments
```

figureout_data

```
    userid       Frequency  Category    tonumber      fromnumber
0   axisbankltdi    13705               9156283564    56454
1   nokiasiemens34  8642                9985986589    54545
2   videocond2h     4699                32354654665   36259
3   pnb             3201                5465546646    414845
4   nokiasiemens7   2536                54354615454   551456
5   one97paytm      2318                45456465146   465466
6   nokiasiemens34  8642                9985986589    54545
7   videocond2h     4699                32354654665   36259
8   pnb             3201                5465546646    414845
9   nokiasiemens7   2536                54354615454   551456
```

expected output:

```
    userid       Frequency  Category    tonumber      fromnumber
0   axisbankltdi    13705    BFSI       9156283564    56454
1   nokiasiemens34  8642     Telecom    9985986589    54545
2   videocond2h     4699     Utilities  32354654665   36259
3   pnb             3201     BFSI       5465546646    414845
4   nokiasiemens7   2536     Telecom    54354615454   551456
5   one97paytm      2318     BFSI       45456465146   465466
6   nokiasiemens34  8642     Telecom    9985986589    54545
7   videocond2h     4699     Utilities  32354654665   36259
8   pnb             3201     BFSI       5465546646    414845
9   nokiasiemens7   2536     Telecom       54354615454   551456
```

So i need to fill the variable called Categories by looking at category_data.  please help me on this

Comment: Is this pandas? If so see related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25493625/vlookup-in-pandas-using-join

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers I am very new to python, so i don't know much about vlookup in python. So please hep me how to write the code for the above in python

Comment: @EdChum , that doesn't look comfortable for me , So please help me in this way

Comment: You've not answered my question, is this pandas? Also SO is not a code writing service

Answer (score 0):

You want a join (called a merge in pandas) it is sort of the database equivalent of a vlookup. That is how I was taught it originally.

Second Edcum's link. I think that's all you need.

Answer (score 0):

create a dictionary with userid, category as key, value

```
user_category = dict(zip(category_data['userid'], category_data['Category']))
```

Map your required column with this dict

```
figureout_data['Category'] = figureout_data['userid'].map(user_category)
```