# Mapping data from 2 dataframes in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes which I need to map and final output should look like this.

> Input 1

```
LPAR    DC
A       LA
B       NY
C       CT
D       VA
E       WO
```

> Input 2

```
LPAR    PROD
A       Microsoft
A       Symantec
A       Vmware
B       Compuware
C       BMC
B       CA
```

> Final Output

```
LPAR    DC  PROD
A       LA  Microsoft
A       LA  Symantec
A       LA  Vmware
B       NY  Compuware
B       NY  CA
C       CT  BMC
D       VA  
E       WO
```

Comment: really similar to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25493625/vlookup-in-pandas-using-join basically you can `merge` or `map` to do this. e.g. `input1.merge(input2, on='LPAR', how='left')` or `input1['PROD'] = input1['LPAR'].map(input2.set_index('LPAR')['PROD'], na_action='ignore').fillna('')`

Comment: That also worked thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `merge` two DataFrames and `fillna` with empty string

```
dict1 = {'LPAR': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'], 
            'DC': ['LA', 'NY', 'CT', 'VA', 'WO']}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(dict1)

dict2 = {'LPAR': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C'], 
             'PROD': ['Microsoft', 'Symantec', 'Vmware', 'Compuware', 'CA', 'BMC']}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(dict2)

df3 = df1.merge(df2, on='LPAR', how='outer').fillna('')
```