# Error on vlookup in python

Tags: python, vlookup

```
  INPUT TABLEs                   OUTPUT TABLE(Table2)     
Table1.csv   | Table2.csv              Table2.csv   
Key          |   Key                Key     Flag
a            |    a                 a        1
b            |    b                 b        1
c            |    c                 c        1
f            |    d                 d        0
             |    e                 e        0
             |    f                 f        1
```

Table1.csv & Table2.csv has a common Key column. If Table2.csv and Table1.csv has the same key,then i need to flag in Table2.csv as 1 else 0.

[I tried this as well. It doesnt work.Nothing gets copied or flagged -  https://stackoverflow.com/a/25493765/9774860]

```
- table1['flag']=table2.key.map(table1.key)
```

Comment: Hi. You are more likely to get help if your problem is explained clearly, and you show what you have tried already and how it didn't work. See [ask].

Comment: Please post (*edit* your question) your actual code (with variable names) rather than just a link and also explain exactly what didn't work.

Comment: Thanks! I am new to stackoverflow

Comment: @Dan:Code -  table1['flag']=table2.key.map(table1.key) . I tried this vlookup concept.This code runs without any error.But, the column flag is empty.

Comment: @Unknown - no, you need to ***edit*** your question. Not post code in the comments where it is unreadable. Also, you must post the code to generate `t1` and `t2`, don't make us guess what data structure you've used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Impossible to answer because you haven't shown what data structure you've used but here is a simple example using lists:

```
>>> t1 = ['a','b','c','f']
>>> t2 = ['a','b','c','d','e','f']
>>> flag = [t2_elem in t1 for t2_elem in t2]
>>> flag
[True, True, True, False, False, True]
```

Or assuming a DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame(t1, columns=['Key'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(t2, columns=['Key'])
df1['Flag']=1
df3 = pd.merge(df2, df1, on='Key, how='left')
df3.fillna(0)
```

outputs

```
   Key  Flag
0    a   1.0
1    b   1.0
2    c   1.0
3    d   0.0
4    e   0.0
5    f   1.0
```