# How to do a vlookup in pandas with different primary key and foreign key column names in two dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas

Lets say we have two dataframes df and df1 with different column names like sku as primary key and sno as its foreign key:

```
Example1(df)
sku loc flag  
122  61 True 
123  61 True
113  62 True 
122  62 True 
123  62 False
122  63 False
301  63 True 

Example2(df1)
sno dept 
113 a
122 b
123 b
301 c
```

I want to do a join or merge which looks like this:

```
Example3
sku loc flag   dept  
122  61 True   b
123  61 True   b
113  62 True   a
122  62 True   b
123  62 False  b
122  63 False  b
301  63 True   c
```

Unfortunately `df.merge(df1, on='sku', how='left')` and `df['dept']=df.sku.map(df1.dept)` doesn't work.

Example modified from : [vlookup in Pandas using join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25493625/vlookup-in-pandas-using-join)

Comment: I blieve `df.merge` will work if you just change the `snow` column to be named `sku`.

Comment: Yes it will work but I wanted to know if we can do without changing column names. Anyways thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you have to set the left and right key

```
df1.merge(df2, right_on='sno',left_on='sku',how='left')


   sku  loc   flag  sno dept
0  122   61   True  122    b
1  123   61   True  123    b
2  113   62   True  113    a
3  122   62   True  122    b
4  123   62  False  123    b
5  122   63  False  122    b
6  301   63   True  301    c
```